# symfony2 with doctrine cannot connect to remote mysql database

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm deploying my symfony2 project and I'm having problems with the database connection to a remote mysql server. It seems like symfony was still trying to connect to a local mysql instance (using socket instead of tcp) and not taking into account the parameteres.yml where are the correct settings.

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
  database_driver:   pdo_mysql
  database_host:     subdomain-example.dotcloud.net
  database_port:     44569
  database_name:     db_platform
  database_user:     root
  database_password: [intentionally hidden]
```

**config.yml**

```
imports:
  - { resource: parameters.yml }

doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection:       default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:           %database_driver%
            dbname:           %database_name%
            user:             %database_user%
            password:         %database_password%
            host:             %database_host%
            port:             %database_port%
            charset:          UTF8
```

**Error stack trace** (shown by the console when I try to clear cache or by the http browser)

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
in /var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 2336
at PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=db_platform', 'root', '****') in /var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 2336
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getPdoService() in /var/www/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 209
at Container->get('pdo') in /var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3027
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSession_Handler_PdoService() in /var/www/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 209
at Container->get('session.handler.pdo') in /var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3053
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSession_Storage_NativeService() in /var/www/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 209
at Container->get('session.storage.native') in /var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3014
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSessionService() in /var/www/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 209
at Container->get('session') in /var/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/EventListener/SessionListener.php line 52
........
```

As you can see above there is no "localhost" in the config file and in the error stack trace the construct method is not passing the host and port data to the PDO class:

```
PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=db_platform', 'root', '****')
```

I have already deleted the cache folder manually.

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.1.0",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.3.0,<2.4.*-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": ">=2.1",
    "doctrine/mongodb": "1.0.1",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*", 
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
    .... more
},
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance,
Mauro

Comment: I know you have cleared your cache (deleted and recreated the directory?) but, silly question: the parameters.yml you show us here is the one on your server right?

Comment: Just a guess but sometimes machines don't like root to connect remotely.  Maybe try a different mysql user just for kicks?

Comment: Yes, that configuration is the one on my server. The cache directory recreates automatically, I do not have root permission on the server to create it. On the other hand, yes, I have tried with another db user and it didnt work either.

Comment: @carriom so you did delete the cache directory or just run the cache clear command?

Comment: @cheesemacfly I did delete the cache directory manually because the cache:clear command executes with the mentioned PDO error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could figure out the problem, it was the PDO service arguments in config.yml:

```
services:
    pdo:
        class: PDO
        arguments:
            - "mysql:host=%database_host%;port=%database_port%;dbname=%database_name%"
            - %database_user%
            - %database_password%
```

I had to add the host and port parameters.

Thanks for the replies.
Mauro

Answer (score 1):

on newer versions of symfony ( > 3 ) you can simply do (in your .env file) :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://mysql_user_name:your_password@www.theHost.domainName:3306/your_database
```