# Cannot connect to host's db from guest

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

In Ubuntu 12.04 guest on Windows 8.1 host (using VirtualBox), a cloned application cannot connect to the host's database.  Regardless of settings in parameter.yml the following occurs at login:

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
> 'projectmana'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

NB: login credentials are different from database credentials.

#### parameters.yml (in part)

```
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: 192.168.168.205
database_port: null
database_name: projectmana
database_user: root
database_password: root's password
```

I have confirmed that guest OS has pdo_mysql installed.  MySQL client in guest OS can connect to mysql at host's address with either root or projectmana credentials.  I have also attempted the solution of adding PDO parameters as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288776/symfony2-with-doctrine-cannot-connect-to-remote-mysql-database) without success.

#### Update

I've also confirmed that PDO can connect to the host via

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=projectmana;host=192.168.168.205';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'some password';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

echo "We're connected!";
```

Comment: The error message states, that symfony tries to connect to localhost, but in your parameters.yml you have 192.168.168.205 as host. Are you sure, that you don't overwrite the host somewhere in config_(env).yml or similar? And have you cleared the applications cache?

Comment: @Pierre: Interesting thoughts, but parameters are not overwritten in either of the config_(prod/dev) files.  Both prod & dev caches cleared and the error persists.

Comment: @Pierre: But you were right! Turns out that in a fit of ignorance many months ago I had included a parameters.yml file in the bundle and imported it. Doh! If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.